# How to define the correct data format for sending a command to Peripheral?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm sending a command to bluetooth device but got no response return back. What'm I doing wrong for creating the data packet?

Here is the example for the frame format describe by document.
[image]

I've tried on create a data such as:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

    let bytes : [UInt16] = [0x0000, 0x0002, 01, 00]
    let data = Data(bytes: bytes, count: bytes.count)

    self.peripheral.writeValue(data, for: characteristic, type:  CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)

}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor   characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

        if (error != nil) {
            print("didWrite Value for characteristic:\(characteristic)")
        }

    }

}
```

I though I did write value to peripheral success, but after that no any respond of func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor ...) return. Anyone please help?

Comment: This would send only the first 4 bytes of data of your array, [0,0,2,0]. Are you sure that's correct? To me, the doc excerpt reads more like should send the 4 bytes [0,2,1,0] and you should change your definition to use `UInt8`.

Comment: @Gereon Thanks suggestion.  let bytes : [UInt8] = [0x0000, 0x0002, 01, 00], let data = Data(bytes) still not working.

Comment: Try with `let bytes : [UInt8] = [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00]`

Comment: According to the table, it should be `[ 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0 ]`

Comment: Thanks guys, it work finally. I just forget to consider their bytes order with little endian!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse` as the type when calling self.peripheral.writeValue, and according to Apples documentation, you would have no response from the peripheral to indicate whether the write was successful.
 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcharacteristicwritetype/withoutresponse

Is it possible for you to try using `CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse` instead, to see if you get a returned response?